# Generate multiple pages pdf in PHP Loop via AJAX using mPDF library

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, pdf

I am developing a plugin that generates various PDFs using AJAX. I have done all but stuck on generating multiple PDFs for each user using the loop.

I prefer to generate PDF with multiple pages for each user. However, if not possible, then a separate PDF for each user would work as well.

> The below code is generating only one page for probably for the first
> user in the loop. Then generate one blank page and stop the iteration.

Please see [mPDF](https://mpdf.github.io/) Library

### Data

```
Array
(
    [group_name] => Food Lovers
    [group_admin] => John Doe
    [identifier] => AtR4deAVgU4Ensi1_1ac2b33a4df7c5f0cf148d6232074352
    [group_order_number] => 1615962332298
    [start_date] => 2021-03-20
    [group_user_ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 63
            [1] => 73
            [2] => 83
        )

    [63] => Array
        (
            [products] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 100
                            [order_number] => 2021031729863
                            [group_order_number] => 1615962332298
                            [product] => 100
                            [product_option] => 
                            [qty] => 6
                            [group_id] => 298
                            [group_admin] => 72
                            [group_user] => 63
                            [identifier] => AtR4deAVgU4Ensi1_1ac2b33a4df7c5f0cf148d6232074352
                            [added_at] => 2021-03-17 10:25:32
                            [price] => 428
                            [total] => 2568
                            [product_name] => Ea ad doloribus consequuntur et qui nihil
                            [customers] => Array
                                (
                                    [Subotdh Ringo_subs@slksk.com] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => Subotdh Ringo
                                            [email] => subs@slksk.com
                                            [qty] => 2
                                            [total_qty] => 8
                                        )

                                    [Chintamani_schd@hkhk.com] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => Chintamani
                                            [email] => schd@hkhk.com
                                            [qty] => 4
                                            [total_qty] => 17
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    ...

                )

            [product_groups] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [order_number] => 2021031729863
                            [group_order_number] => 1615962332298
                            [product_group] => 40
                            [qty] => 6
                            [group_id] => 298
                            [group_admin] => 72
                            [group_user] => 63
                            [customers] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => Subotdh Ringo
                                            [email] => subs@slksk.com
                                            [qty] => 2
                                            [discount] => 316
                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => Chintamani
                                            [email] => schd@hkhk.com
                                            [qty] => 4
                                            [discount] => 632
                                        )

                                )

                            [identifier] => AtR4deAVgU4Ensi1_1ac2b33a4df7c5f0cf148d6232074352
                            [added_at] => 2021-03-17 10:25:32
                            [price] => 1621
                            [discount] => 158
                            [discounted_price] => 1463
                            [total] => 8778
                            [product_count] => 4
                            [product_group_name] => Quibusdam unde
                        )

                    ...

                )

            [pg_discount] => Array
                (
                    [Subotdh Ringo_subs@slksk.com] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Subotdh Ringo
                            [email] => subs@slksk.com
                            [total_qty] => 2
                            [total_discount] => 316
                        )

                    [Chintamani_schd@hkhk.com] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Chintamani
                            [email] => schd@hkhk.com
                            [total_qty] => 4
                            [total_discount] => 632
                        )

                    [Dingon Dksi_sdk@fkfg.com] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Dingon Dksi
                            [email] => sdk@fkfg.com
                            [total_qty] => 1
                            [total_discount] => 150
                        )

                )

        )

        ...
)
```

### Callback Function

```
function gs_group_users_order_pdf_generator_ajax()
{
    // Check if user is logged in
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in()) {
        // throw error if user is not logged in
        wp_send_json_error(__('Please login to order', 'group-shop'));

        // we use this manually as want to print error
        wp_die();
    }

    // Check if user is logged in
    if ( ! current_user_can('administrator')) {
        // throw error if user is not logged in
        wp_send_json_error(__('You are not authorized to perform this action', 'group-shop'));

        // we use this manually as want to print error
        wp_die();
    }

    // check and validate nonce
    if ( ! check_ajax_referer('gs_nonce', 'nonce', FALSE)) {

        // throw error if validation fails
        wp_send_json_error(__('Do not be nasty with validation', 'group-shop'));

        // we use this manually as want to print error
        wp_die();
    }

    $action             = $_POST[ 'action' ];
    $nonce              = $_POST[ 'nonce' ];
    $group_order_number = $_POST[ 'group_order_number' ];
    $group_id           = $_POST[ 'group_id' ];
    $group_admin_id     = $_POST[ 'group_admin' ];
    $identifier         = $_POST[ 'identifier' ];
    $status             = $_POST[ 'status' ];
    $group              = get_the_title($group_id);
    $group_admin        = get_userdata($group_admin_id);

    $order          = new Group_Shop_Order();
    $data           = $order->prepare_group_users_orders_pdf_data($group_order_number, $group_id, $group_admin_id, $identifier);
    $group_user_ids = $data[ 'group_user_ids' ];
    $filename       = $group_order_number . '.pdf';

    ob_clean();

    // init mpdf
    try {
        $mpdf = new Mpdf([
            'default_font_size' => 6,
            'default_font'      => 'Helvetica',
            'orientation'       => 'L',
        ]);

        // write pdf
        $stylesheet                 = file_get_contents(GROUP_SHOP_ROOT . 'public/css/invoice.css');
        $mpdf->shrink_tables_to_fit = 1;
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);

        foreach ($group_user_ids as $group_user_id) :

            $user_data = get_userdata($group_user_id);

            header('Content-type: application/pdf');
            header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

            // create pdf
            $markup = '<div class="info">';
            $markup .= '<p><strong>' . __('User', 'group-shop') . ':</strong> ' . $user_data->display_name . '</p>';
            $markup .= '<p><strong>Email:</strong> ' . $user_data->user_email . '</p>';
            $markup .= '<p><strong>Admin:</strong> ' . $data[ 'group_admin' ] . '</p>';
            $markup .= '<p><strong>Group:</strong> ' . $data[ 'group_name' ] . '</p>';
            $markup .= '</div>';

            $markup .= '<table class="table">';
                // table markup
            $markup .= '</table>';

            // end of order table

            $markup .= '<pagebreak />';  //page break

        endforeach; // $group_user_ids end

        $mpdf->WriteHTML($markup, HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY, TRUE);

        // create directory if not exists
        $orders_dirname  = 'tvm-orders' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'user-orders';
        $orders_root_dir = WP_CONTENT_DIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $orders_dirname;
        $orders_pdf_dir  = $orders_root_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $group_order_number;
        $order_pdf_url   = content_url($orders_dirname . '/' . $group_order_number . '/' . $filename);
        $success_message = __('Group User Orders PDF is generated and opened in another tab.', 'group-shop');

        // check if pdf is exists, just open it
        // @todo uncomment in production
    //        if (file_exists($orders_pdf_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename)) {
    //
    //            wp_send_json_success([
    //                'message'      => $success_message,
    //                'redirect_url' => $order_pdf_url,
    //            ], 200);
    //        }

        // create directory
        if ( ! is_dir($orders_pdf_dir)) {
            // create directories
            wp_mkdir_p($orders_pdf_dir);
            // create index.php file for root and sub-folders
            gs_create_file_recursively($orders_root_dir, 'index.php');
        }

        // save pdf file
        $mpdf->Output($orders_pdf_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename, 'F');

        // show success message once record updated
        wp_send_json_success([
            'message'       => $success_message,
            'generated_url' => $order_pdf_url,
        ], 200);

    } catch
    (MpdfException $e) {
        // throw error if fails to insert record
        wp_send_json_error(__('Something went wrong', 'group-shop'));
    }

    ob_end_flush();

}

// hook the function
add_action('wp_ajax_gs_group_users_order_pdf_generator', 'gs_group_users_order_pdf_generator_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_gs_group_users_order_pdf_generator', 'gs_group_users_order_pdf_generator_ajax');
```

### Javascript

#### Calling function

```
// to generate group user orders pdfs
$(document).on('click', '.gs-guo-pdf-orders', function () {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to generate group users order PDFs?')) {
        // process ajax data
        ajax_process.call(this, '', 'gs_group_users_order_pdf_generator', 'fa-window-close');
    }
});
```

#### Compelete Javascript

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {

        let response_alert = $('#response');
        response_alert.hide();

        /**
         * process ajax data
         *
         * @param {string} status - Order status. Available options are P, C, D
         * @param icon
         * @param action
         * @returns void
         */
        function ajax_process(status, action, icon) {
            // process data
            let data_order_num = $(this).data('ordernum');
            let data_gid = $(this).data('gid');
            let data_gadmin = $(this).data('gadmin');
            let data_identifier = $(this).data('identifier');

            // button feedback and disable
            $(this).find('i').removeClass(icon).addClass('fa-sync-alt');
            $(this).addClass('updating').prop('disabled', true);

            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                context: this,
                url: ajax_vars.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    action: action,
                    nonce: ajax_vars.nonce,
                    group_order_number: data_order_num,
                    group_id: data_gid,
                    group_admin: data_gadmin,
                    identifier: data_identifier,
                    status: status,
                },
                success: function (response) {

                    if (response.success === true) {
                        // get the response message
                        let message = response.data.message;

                        // display success message
                        response_alert.fadeIn().prepend(alerts('success', message));

                        // redirect if already exists
                        if (response.data.redirect_url !== undefined) {
                            // window.location.href = response.data.redirect_url;
                            window.open(
                                response.data.redirect_url,
                                '_blank'
                            )
                        }

                        // redirect if newly generated
                        if (response.data.generated_url !== undefined) {
                            // window.location.href = response.data.redirect_url;
                            window.open(
                                response.data.generated_url,
                                '_blank'
                            )
                        }

                    }

                    if (response.success === false) {
                        response_alert.fadeIn().prepend(alerts('error', response.data));
                    }
                    gs_alert_stats();

                    // update datatables data
                    $('#gsAllOrdersTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    let error_message = (response.data === undefined) ? 'Something went wrong!' : response.data;
                    response_alert.fadeIn().prepend(alerts('error', error_message));
                    gs_alert_stats();
                },
                complete: function () {

                    $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-sync-alt').addClass('fa-check');
                    $(this).removeClass('updating').prop('disabled', false);
                }
            });
        }

        // to deliver
        $(document).on('click', '.gs-deliver-order', function () {
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to change status to Deliver?')) {
                //process ajax data
                ajax_process.call(this, 'D', 'gs_status_group_order_item', 'fa-shipping-fast');
            }
        });

        // to pending
        $(document).on('click', '.gs-pending-order', function () {
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to change status to Pending?')) {
                //process ajax data
                ajax_process.call(this, 'P', 'gs_status_group_order_item', 'fa-exclamation-triangle');
            }
        });

        // to cancel
        $(document).on('click', '.gs-cancel-order', function () {
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to change status to Cancel?')) {
                // process ajax data
                ajax_process.call(this, 'C', 'gs_status_group_order_item', 'fa-window-close');
            }
        });

        // to generate group order pdf
        $(document).on('click', '.gs-go-pdf-order', function () {
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to generate a group order PDF?')) {
                // process ajax data
                ajax_process.call(this, '', 'gs_group_order_pdf_generator', 'fa-window-close');
            }
        });

        // to generate group user orders pdfs
        $(document).on('click', '.gs-guo-pdf-orders', function () {
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to generate group users order PDFs?')) {
                // process ajax data
                ajax_process.call(this, '', 'gs_group_users_order_pdf_generator', 'fa-window-close');
            }
        });

        /**
         * response alert
         */
        function gs_alert_stats() {
            let gs_alert = $('.gs-message');
            $('.gs-close').on('click', function () {
                alerts('Clicked');
                $(this).parent(gs_alert).fadeOut();
            });
        }


    });
})(jQuery);
```

### HTML for Button

```
<button class="gs-guo-pdf-orders btn btn-sm btn-outline-info ml-3" type="button" title="Generate Group Users Order PDFs" 
data-ordernum="1615962332298" data-gid="298" data-gadmin="72" data-identifier="AtR4deAVgU4Ensi1_1ac2b33a4df7c5f0cf148d6232074352">
<i class="fas fa-copy"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the problem. But you are rewriting $markup variable every loop in the foreach with this sentence:

```
$markup = '<div class="info">';
```

You must to define $markup as empty before the foreach and then concatenate strings inside the foreach

```
$markup = ''; //<-- Add this first

// Headers are better out of the loop
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
foreach ($group_user_ids as $group_user_id) {

    $user_data = get_userdata($group_user_id);

    // create pdf
    $markup .= '<div class="info">'; //<-- Concat here, you are rewriting
    $markup .= '<p><strong>' . __('User', 'group-shop') . ':</strong> ' . $user_data->display_name . '</p>';
    $markup .= '<p><strong>Email:</strong> ' . $user_data->user_email . '</p>';
    $markup .= '<p><strong>Admin:</strong> ' . $data[ 'group_admin' ] . '</p>';
    $markup .= '<p><strong>Group:</strong> ' . $data[ 'group_name' ] . '</p>';
    $markup .= '</div>';

    $markup .= '<table class="table">';
        // table markup
    $markup .= '</table>';

    // end of order table

    $markup .= '<pagebreak />';  //page break

} // $group_user_ids end
$mpdf->WriteHTML($markup, HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY, TRUE);
```

Comment: Wow, you are probably, correct. This could be the issue. I will check and back to you tomorrow. day end here today :) Thanks for the input.

Comment: Sorry for being delay. but before I check and accept the answer I need to finish a few things in the plugin I am writing. So I will accept and reply soon as I check it. Just because other devs also can consider your answer for the same problem.

Comment: Yes, the problem was as you mentiond. It is a silly mistake...